# Return in recursive backtracking algorithm doesn't work

Tags: python, recursion, return, backtracking

I've made a backtracking algorithm for the twoSum problem. It's far from efficient but it works, atleast while printing the answer it shows the correct answer, but when returning the answer it returns the empty list instead of the value calculated in the if statement.

This is the code I used.

```
def twoSum(nums, target, res=[], k=0):
    if target == 0:
        return [nums.index(res[0]), nums.index(res[1])]

    else:
        for i in range(k, len(nums)):
            if target - nums[i] >= 0:
                target = target - nums[i]
                res.append(nums[i])
                twoSum(nums, target, res, k+1)
                res.pop()
                target = target + nums[i]

    return []


nums = [2, 7, 11, 15]
print(twoSum(nums, 9))
```

EDIT: the twoSum problem is basically this:

```
Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
Output: [0,1]
Explanation: Because nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1].
```

How do I make sure that the return statement within the if statement actually gives the ending result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldnt it be return [target] instead of return [] ? i might be unfamiliar with the coding language but that doesnt seem correct

Comment: uhm no i dont think so, the return [] is for the case that there is no solution. So it returns the empty list

Comment: Do you return it anywhere else besides when it is 0 ? i dont see any return in the IF as pointed by you. Can you please clarify what programming language it is ?

Comment: What do you mean? I return it in the if statement whenever the if statement is true? And then when it can not find a solution it returns in the else statement? That return statement might need a tab, but that won't fix my problem. I think because of the recursion it just returns and goes back 1 step. But it won't fully return the answer

Comment: Ah now i see sry the formatting thew me off, maybe you should create a list with those 2 values and then return it ? idk the compiler sometimes messes things up soo it would rule it out with a cast or an object thats specifically a List

Comment: Well i tried simply returning an integer in the if statement but that also doesn't show. Its 100% because of the recursion. Since it does return it sometimes during the recursion but it doesnt return it as a final answer

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem I see is this common recursion beginner's error:

```
twoSum(nums, target, res, k+1)
```

You call `twoSum()` knowing it returns a value, but you ignore the returned value and move onto the next test.  You need to check the return value:

```
if result := twoSum(nums, target, res, k+1):
    return result
```

Try that to see if you get a better answer.

The dangerous default value issue that @Blckknght raises, with which I agree (+1), focuses on this line:

```
return [nums.index(res[0]), nums.index(res[1])]
```

Which uses the `res` array but leaves values on it for the next call:

```
>>> nums = [2, 7, 11, 15]
>>> print(twoSum(nums, 9))
[0, 1]
>>> print(twoSum(nums, 18))
[0, 1]
>>>
```

Because we didn't clear `res`, we keep getting the previous result.  Here's a simple attempt to address the problem (and not use the walrus operator per the OP's request):

```
def twoSum(nums, target, res=[], k=0):
    if target == 0:
        return [nums.index(res.pop()), nums.index(res.pop())]

    for i in range(k, len(nums)):
        if target - nums[i] >= 0:
            target -= nums[i]
            res.append(nums[i])

            result = twoSum(nums, target, res, k+1)

            if result:  # not empty list
                return result

            target += nums[i]
            res.pop()

    return []
```

You'll need to run it through combinations of tests (solvable and not) to convince yourself it's working.  Preferably, it'd be nice to solve this without a dangerous default value (and without introducing a global!)

Comment: yes, that works! What does that := exactly do? I've never seen an approach like this, could I rewrite my code a bit differently to make it work without this?

Comment: This correctly diagnoses the issue, but I'd note that there's some peril in this code, as `res` is a mutable default argument, and the only thing preventing it from accumulating cruft is the fact that the code removes each element that gets added to it as the recursion unwinds. If you change the return logic, you need to change the `res` maintenance logic too (or just avoid the mutable default argument in the first place).

Comment: @Blckknght, I understand and agree. I squashed the immediate bug but there are implications to the *next* call to `twoSum()` if `res` isn't clear upon exit.  Hopefully the OP will take your comments to heart and tweak their code.

Comment: @Blckknght, I expanded my answer to discuss this problem and suggest a solution.